# Am I getting the details of mechanism of adsorption right?

Tags: surface-chemistry

Particles on the surface of a substance have a net force towards the geometric center of the substance called residual force.
When molecules come close enough to the surface of a substance the residual force due to the substance pulls them on to the surface thus adsorbing them.

is this right?

if not then, give a detailed account on the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The process of adsorption involves separation of a substance from one phase accompanied by its accumulation or concentration at the surface of another. The adsorbing phase is the adsorbent, and the material concentrated or adsorbed at the surface of that phase is the adsorbate.